# Select records when combination of data fields match against same and different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table that holder transactional data similar to below:

```
TransactionID |FirstTType |FirstTDate |SecondTType |SecondTDate |
T1 |A | 01/01/2019 |
T2 |C | 01/02/2019 |
T3 |E | 01/01/2019 |
T4 |D | 02/02/2019 |
T5 |C | 01/02/2019 |
T6 |Z | 01/02/2019 |
```

From the example above, I have in Row T2, FirstTType and FirstTDate both has the same data as row T5.

I expect to get the below return

```
TransactionID |FirstTType |FirstTDate |SecondTType |SecondTDate |
T2 |C | 01/02/2019 |
T5 |C | 01/02/2019 |
```

I wonder if there is a good way to do this in SQL server

Thanks

Comment: What's the point or relevance of the last two columns, which you don't use or refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're searching for repeating values of those two columns, then consider grouping by them and using with `having count(*)>1` :

```
 select TransactionID, FirstTType, FirstTDate
   from tab t
  where exists
              ( select FirstTType, FirstTDate
                  from tab
                 where FirstTType = t.FirstTType
                   and FirstTDate = t.FirstTDate
                 group by FirstTType, FirstTDate
                having count(*) > 1 )
```

where I suppose `TransactionID` is a primary key value.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ceef3a67172ef24bf4916411f69bd92b)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.FirstTType = t.FirstTType and
                    t2.FirstTDate = t.FirstTDate and
                    t2.TransactionID <> t.TransactionID
             );
```